# Image "look like press down" when single tap

Tags: windows-phone-7

After created an image with Tap gesture, when "tap" on the image, it does fire up the "GestureListener_Tap".  However, the user experience is bad since when user tap on the image, the image won't "indent down" or look like pressing down...

Anyone know how to do that please?

```
<Image Source="images/Forex 1 Icons_62.png" Stretch="None" Margin="0,500,0,0">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing newer used an Image as a Button, most of the time i wrapped the image inside a button and then you get the Effects because it is a button. Maybe you would have to add the to the Image an Effect for example the `toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled` or you need to do it the hard way and create New States for the Image and change the state if the user Taps the image manually.